# How do connect to a SQL Server Visible in remote Desktop

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot, remote-desktop

I am an employee of an organisation which uses Remote Desktop Computers. We log in from personal devices with Windows Remote Desktop to an IP/port combo, say 12.23.1.234:5431.

Once in I have servers accessible on the root path e.g. SVR1

Our main software uses a SQL Server instance on SVR1 e.g. Database_01. I can see this on the software loading screen and switch between SVR1\Database_01 and SVR1\Database_02 etc.

How can I identify the server name/address to connect MS Powerpivot to this server directly from my personal machine?

Comment: May not be able to. Unless the SQL Server is exposed on the IP 12.23.1.234, or you have a VPN connection to the server. consult the network administrator of your organisation

Answer (score 0):

For this you have static ip address provided by your isp provider or your machine should have connected to your VPN and if you have  one of them then you can access database by enabling tcp/ip in sql server in host machine
for this open SQL Server management configuration
in configuration tab go to
SQL Native Client *.0 Configuration =>Client Protocol
then Right Click on TCP/IP in right panel and make it enable

after that you can able to access sql server remotely by using ip address in server name

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below mentioned steps to connect to SQL server remotely on a remote desktop:

Configure SQL Server machine
Windows Firewall ->Advanced Settings->Inbound Rules.
Run SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) on SQL Server machine.
Server Properties - > Connections -> Allow Remote Connections ..”
Add a SQL login (if not already there)
Enable SQL Service to listen on TCP/IP.
Restart SQL Server Service.